# getting two column sticky working with css scroll snap

Tags: css, css-position, scroll-snap

I am trying to get sticky positioning to work with scroll snap but I am having difficulties.

I looked at the example on CSS Tricks (in codepen link) on how to use scroll snap and found it breaks if you don't have

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

on the container (commented out on line 3). But if you do, then it breaks my two column sticky scrolling. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can use both?

https://codepen.io/shellwe/pen/abzgNzQ

If not anyone have some good suggestions on how to achieve the scroll snap in JS? I found this that may work but I would love to have the CSS handle it for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/kZY9R/79/

Comment: May be this article helps you for scroll snapping: https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/

Comment: Thank you! I linked to that scroll snapping article in my coepen. I can get scroll-snap to work, and I can get sticky to work. In the example you linked to you break scroll snap if you comment out "overflow-y: scroll" on the container but if you add that style to the container in my example (as commented out) it breaks sticky

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes by this, the reason you need the overflow-y: scroll is because you also need a set height and it scrolls within that constraint. I finally got back to this project and took a while to figure out why it won't work.

Cheers!